# How to retrieve all instances of one type from DynamoDB table?

Tags: nosql, amazon-dynamodb

I am new to the NoSQL world. I want to build a table where I want to store 2 completely different types of instances. First is financial terms and their definitions and some more attributes, second, video links, and their descriptions and more. So the point here is that I want those in one table, and I want to have a query that retrieves all financial terms obj and one more that retrieves all video links obj. So I can do the scan method, but I will need to filter out half of the table. So what should be the structure for such a task?

Comment: Since they are completely different, why not store them in separate tables?

Answer (score 0):

It's absolutely fine to store different entities in the same table, you just need to prefix them.

With Dynamo you have to think in advance what your query patterns are. If you have a future need to join entities, you should use single table plus GSI (Global Index) on a common attribute to emulate joins.

Please have a look at official docs on DynamoDB design https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/bp-general-nosql-design.html

However, for your particular case it doesn't make sense as you want to retrieve all entities at once.

This can be achieved by having single `HASH KEY` to group entities and different `SORT KEY` for storing entities inside this group, like

```
PK    SK
TERMS TERM#xxx
TERMS TERM#yyy
LINKS LINK#xxx
LINKS LINK#yyy
```

By warned though, that you might hit read/write limits if you put all records into single `HASH KEY` partition.

You can think of `HASH KEY` as a book shelf which stores books in alphabetical order `SORT KEY`. This way you will have two shelves for terms and links, which stores corresponding entities.

Please also note that DynamoDB `limit` is not the same `limit` in SQL sense. More details https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Query.html#Query.Limit